# How to do localization?

Tags: android, localization

im really neww to the term localization, can any one of you expound, i've been searching for good references. can anyone of you provide me some good references or can anyone of you explain about this matter to give me more insights

Comment: That's a rather vague question. What's your objective? If it's just to learn the meaning of the term, why have web searches been insufficient? If it's to implement it in the context of a particular technology or framework, we'd probably need to know which ones.

Comment: in the context of implementing this on a certain tech or framework, i really don't know the process even the basic, can't find any good source

Comment: Based on your other questions with the res/values/strings.xml and the other locales come e.g. in values-de, values-es and so on.

Comment: hmmm dats on android, but what is localization really? an overview would be an headsup and some pointers would be good

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just need to create a seperate `strings.xml` file for every language you want to support.

Your fallback language is in the directory `res/values`. Your german translation would be in `res/values-de`, the spanish one in `res/values-es` and so on.

Read also the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) about that.

Comment: so u mean every variable that is declared in strings with its equivalent word say in en

Comment: Your comment seems to be incompleated but yes, if you have 3 versions of a text variable e.g. `R.string.welcome` `getResources().getString(R.string.welcome)` would return on an english device *"Welcome"* and on a german device *"Willkommen"*.